# Perl adding array with another array

Tags: arrays, perl, addition

I cam across the code below online where it's trying to add two array. Can anyone explain what it is calculating to get 14?

```
my @a = (1,2,5)+(8,9);
print "@a";

output: 14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output is 14 as `$a[0]` is 14 => `5+9`

`+` operator imposes scalar context on both lists so last elements are taken and added,

```
# in scalar context $x is assigned with last element
my $x = (1,2,5);
print "\$x is $x\n";
```

outputs `$x is 5`

`warnings` pragma would also complain, giving you a hint that something fishy is going on,

```
Useless use of a constant (8) in void context
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting with:

```
my @a = (1,2,5)+(8,9);
```

When using a list in a [`scalar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) context, the last element is returned.  Consult [`What is the difference between a list and an array?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array%3f) for details.

Therefore the above two lists reduce to:

```
my @a = 5 + 9;
```

Which mathematically equals:

```
my @a = (14);
```